# How to auto resize images within div?

Tags: css, image, resize

EDIT: Figured it out by myself https://gyazo.com/afc898b2bd2ed387efd9b598c5a1eed5

Thanks for trying

On the right side of each image, there is empty black spaces.  I'm looking for information on how to bring the images from the rows under to take up as much space as possible and re-size itself even if it means squeezing in.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjpwLw

```
   *{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;


}

body{
left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#000;

}

.top{
background-color:#333;
width:100%;
height: 50px;
position: relative;



}

img{
position: relative;
top: 55px;
left: 55px;
max-height: 304px;
width: auto;
padding: 0.05%  0.05%;
border-radius:5px;


}

img:hover{
opacity:0.4;


}
```

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you would like to achieve. Empty black spaces? Aren't you setting a padding, thus empty black spaces? Or what empty black spaces?

Comment: I would like the outcome to be like this: https://gyazo.com/21e9fbe7b10065276ef843150d794b7b BUT with the images actually resized... in the picture you see, you can scroll to the right to see the rest of the image                                                                                 ----> The images on the right side of the page shouldn't allow you to continue to go further right but rather RE-SIZE itself to fit in any missing space.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :nth-child() to access each index then give it width:

```css
.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img{
  height: 150px;
}
img:nth-child(1), img:nth-child(5){
  width: 30%;
}
img:nth-child(2){
  width: 25%;
}
img:nth-child(3){
  width: 25%;
}
img:nth-child(4){
  width: 18%;
}
img:nth:-child(6){
  width: 30%;
}
img:nth-child(7){
  width: 24%;
}
img:nth-child(8){
  width: 16%;
}
```

```html
 <div class = "container">
  <div class = "top">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444124746228-e0356266964d?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=950&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1700"  alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416183793821-cfdaa8c72745?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=e4f4b36f5409245ba8c9fe11bd408ce1" alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1417261726333-db38183ebcb1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=a048b87acf17ebac312f25e80338b4a5" alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/yZfr4jmxQyuaE132MWZm_stagnes.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=56ac51ed7e3597101bf9450fe1fa5f49" alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446117788378-6805add75533?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=950&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1700" alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/6/lighthouse.jpg?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=950&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1700" alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447756285628-47953ed14e2d?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=950&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1700" alt="" />
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/D4zfsMrIT3i4Fuxqs5Gm_13129149325_7560b79cf2_o.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=69e8ba306a54c810d2c807933e3f97f0" alt="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.top` div you can increase the width so that another image can fit into the next space. Use this CSS with your codePen.

```
* {
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#000;
}

.top{
    background-color:#333;
    width:130%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 304px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.05%  0.05%;
    border-radius:5px;
    float: left;
}

img:hover{
    opacity:0.4;
}
```